# Cant get my SOAP Web service using Axis2 to run on weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weblogic, apache-axis

I have a web service that runs perfectly on Apache tomcat but the same war when run on weblogic only shows Version web service .

Do i need to create a fresh project with runtime as Weblogic.?or are there some modifications that i can do in the same war file to get it working.

The Error from weblogic's log is:

```
axisconfiguration getrepository returns null ,cannot deploy scripts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working by Using an unpacked war and then deploying it.
See this for help https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html

And Second method that involves no unpacking of the war is:

Create a .aar (Axis Archive ) of your webservice ,place it in your
 **Webcontent/WEB-INF/services/** and place an entry of you .aar in **Webcontent/WEB-INF/services.list** then deploy the packed war of your project and run it.

.aar file can be made by Axis Service Archiver Plugin